# BeautifulSoup 4, findNext() function

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm playing with BeautifulSoup 4 and I have this html code:

```
</tr>
          <tr>
<td id="freistoesse">Giraffe</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>7</td>
</tr>
```

I want to match both values between `<td>` tags so here 14 and 7.

I tried this:

```
giraffe = soup.find(text='Giraffe').findNext('td').text
```

but this only matches `14`. How can I match both values with this function?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `find_all` instead of `findNext`:

```
import bs4 as bs
content = '''\
<tr>
<td id="freistoesse">Giraffe</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>7</td>
</tr>'''
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content)

for td in soup.find('td', text='Giraffe').parent.find_all('td'):
    print(td.text)
```

yields

```
Giraffe
14
7
```

---

Or, you could use `find_next_siblings` (also known as `fetchNextSiblings`):

```
for td in soup.find(text='Giraffe').parent.find_next_siblings():
    print(td.text)
```

yields

```
14
7
```

---

**Explanation:**

Note that `soup.find(text='Giraffe')` returns a NavigableString.

```
In [30]: soup.find(text='Giraffe')
Out[30]: u'Giraffe'
```

To get the associated `td` tag, use

```
In [31]: soup.find('td', text='Giraffe')
Out[31]: <td id="freistoesse">Giraffe</td>
```

or

```
In [32]: soup.find(text='Giraffe').parent
Out[32]: <td id="freistoesse">Giraffe</td>
```

Once you have the `td` tag, you could use `find_next_siblings`:

```
In [35]: soup.find(text='Giraffe').parent.find_next_siblings()
Out[35]: [<td>14</td>, <td>7</td>]
```

---

PS. BeautifulSoup has added method names that use underscores instead of CamelCase. They do the same thing, but comform to the PEP8 style guide recommendations. Thus, prefer `find_next_siblings` over `fetchNextSiblings`.

Comment: thanks, dunno why #1 method raised me an error: `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'` ideas?

Comment: `soup.find(text='Giraffe')` returns a `NavigableString`. Using `soup.find('td', text='Giraffe')` gives you the `td` tag instead. From there, call `fetchNextSibling()`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this quick help!