# Webscraping specific sections of page without 'class' or 'id' identifiers

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having issues web-scraping a

tag element while using BeautifulSuop4  in Python. Typically the elements are given a class or id identifier where I can use:

`.find_all(<p>, class_ = 'class-name')`

to find the element however the elements I am trying to isolate are in a consecutive list of

tags all of which have no identifier for their element.

Is there a way to choose every

tag after a tag that has an identifier? Or maybe a way to isolate the specific

tags I want without them having any shared class/id?

Answer (score 0):

You could use find_next_sibling to find the classless next sibling of an element.

Consider this example HTML. The first div has the class "blah". The second div has no class but is beside the first div.

```
html='<div><div class="blah">1</div><div>no class</div></div>'
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
soup.find('div',{'class':"blah"}).find_next_sibling()

#outputs second div without a class
<div>no class</div>
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771424/beautifulsoup-4-findnext-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35141250/access-next-sibling-li-element-with-beautifulsoup) for more details.